# Unable to register device with Fiware-Figway on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, registration, fiware

I am a student currently working on a Fiware project. I am trying to collect noise data using my PI with Fiware and I found this tutorial: https://www.fiware.org/tag/raspberry-pi/.

Now I am at step 2 and I want to register my device but it doesn't seem to work. This is the response I get after I run " ./registerDevice 0001 4IN1 " :

```
root@raspberrypi://home/pi/Desktop/student/fiware-figway/c++# ./registerDevice 0001 4IN1

-> Config file: Debug Level <1>.

-> M2M Platform reply: 
**

**
```

Can anybody help? I'm sure I am missing something I just don't know what.

Comment: Please include more information related to your problem. How is your config file? What M2M platform are you using?